# Cannot access file after changing permissions and reinstalling Windows

Tags: windows, file-permissions

I have example.txt file. I changed access of this file and reinstalled OS. After that I don't have access to this file. How can I get access to this file?

Answer (score 2):

As an administrator, you need to take ownership of the file, then change its permissions.

Answer (score 0):

Please right click this file, select Properties, and then go to the Permissions tab. Press "Change Owner" and in the window that appears type your own username and then OK. You will then be able to change the permissions on this file (via the button below the permissions list, I believe labeled Edit) in order to make it readable/writable by your or others.

The exact text may be wrong, I'm on Linux right now so I can't check.